# Are you sure you want to shut down your [Hackintosh]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Let's shut down our [hackintosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackintosh) (currently 51 questions).

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes. It's about a Hackintosh.

- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. Hackintosh is a more general-computing topic, as are most of the questions in that tag. The only programming questions from the tag that I've seen don't directly relate to the computer being a Hackintosh.

- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. The same details and more could be added by adding a MacOS version tag.

- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes, it's well-defined.

This tag only has 51 questions and I would've done it myself had it not been for the 50-question limit.

From a quick glance, most of the questions with [hackintosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackintosh) are general computing.

Burninate? Burninate. Burninate!

Comment: Are you sure you want to shut down your [Hackintosh]?

Comment: "most of the questions with hackintosh are general computing." please don't send them to [su]. They are off topic there.

Comment: The tag now has only 29 questions, so you might be able to do the abbreviated burnination now.